# How do I remove gesture recogniser from a label in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've bottom toolbar in my ViewController and a TableView above it. The toolbar has a date label in the middle,  and next and previous buttons on the left and right. based on the selected date tableview content changes..

Now TableViewCell contains a UILabel. I want to add Gesture to the label only if the selected day is today.

So I wrote in my cell update method

```
UITapGestureRecognizer gesture = new UITapGestureRecognizer();
gesture.AddTarget(() => HandleValueLabelClick());
if (source.parentController.selectedDateTime.Day == DateTime.Now.Day)
{
    AddEditAction();
    ValueLabel.AddGestureRecognizer(gesture);
}
else
{
    ValueLabel.RemoveGestureRecognizer(gesture);
}
```

But the gesture remove if the selected date is not today, is not working. Any help is appreciated..

Edit:

```
public partial class ProgramCalendarCell : UITableViewCell
{
    NSIndexPath indexPath;

    ProgramVitalsCalendarTableSource source;
    ProgramVital vital;
    ProgramVitalCalendar calendar;

    public ProgramCalendarCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public void UpdateCell(ProgramVital vital, ProgramVitalCalendar calendar, NSIndexPath indexPath, ProgramVitalsCalendarTableSource source)
    {
        this.source = source;
        this.indexPath = indexPath;
        this.vital = vital;
        this.calendar = calendar;

        InitVitalName();
        InitVitalValue();

        NewValueTextField.Hidden = true;
        ValueLabel.Hidden = false;

        UIView separatorLine = new UIView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 44, 1200f, 0.5f));
        separatorLine.BackgroundColor = AZConstants.SeparatorColor;
        ContentView.AddSubview(separatorLine);

        UITapGestureRecognizer gesture = new UITapGestureRecognizer();
        gesture.AddTarget(() => HandleValueLabelClick());
        if (source.parentController.selectedDateTime.Day == DateTime.Now.Day)
        {
            AddEditAction();
            ValueLabel.AddGestureRecognizer(gesture);
        }
        else
        {
            ValueLabel.RemoveGestureRecognizer(gesture);
        }
    }

    void InitVitalName()
    {
        string name = vital.vitalName;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(vital.unitName))
            name += " (" + System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(vital.unitName) + ")";
        VitalNameLabel.Text = name;
    }

    void InitVitalValue()
    {
        string value = "";
        string color = "";
        if (calendar != null)
        {
            value = calendar.values[0].value;
            color = calendar.values[0].color;
        }
        UIHelper.SetVitalValueTileBackGround(ValueLabel, value, color);
    }

    void HandleValueLabelClick()
    {
        ValueLabel.Hidden = true;
        NewValueTextField.Hidden = false;
        NewValueTextField.BecomeFirstResponder();
    }

    void AddEditAction()
    {
        ValueLabel.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
        NewValueTextField.ShouldReturn = (textField) =>
        {
            textField.ResignFirstResponder();
            ValueLabel.Hidden = false;
            NewValueTextField.Hidden = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Row: " + indexPath.Row);
            return true;
        };

        UIToolbar toolbar = new UIToolbar(new RectangleF(0.0f, 0.0f, (float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width, 44.0f));
        toolbar.BarTintColor = AZConstants.PrimaryColor;
        toolbar.TintColor = UIColor.White;
        toolbar.Items = new UIBarButtonItem[]{
            new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace),
                new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, delegate {
                    Console.WriteLine("Row: " + indexPath.Row);
                    SaveReading();
                    NewValueTextField.ResignFirstResponder();
                })
            };
        toolbar.BarTintColor = AZConstants.PrimaryColor;
        toolbar.TintColor = UIColor.White;
        toolbar.Translucent = true;
        toolbar.SizeToFit();
        NewValueTextField.InputAccessoryView = toolbar;

        int vId = Int32.Parse(vital.vitalId);

        if (vId == 20 || vId == 5 || vId == 496)
            NewValueTextField.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.DecimalPad;
        else
            NewValueTextField.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad;
    }

    async void SaveReading()
    {

        var hud = UIHelper.GetProgressHud(source.parentController.View, "");
        hud.Show(animated: true);
        Status status = await VitalHelper.postVitalValue(Constants.__IOS__, vital, NewValueTextField.Text, 0,
                                                         DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt"), "");

        if (status.status)
        {
            source.parentController.FetchAndDisplayVitalValues();
        }
        else
        {
            new UIAlertView("Error", status.message, null, "OK", null).Show();
        }
        hud.Hide(animated: true, delay: 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply don't do the action if it's not today? Else, when do you add exactly the tap gesture? Because depending on where, you may have multiple calls to `HandleValueLabelClick()` (since cells are reused)

Comment: I did't have the else part initially. Still had the same effect.

Comment: @Larme I've posted my full code. Please see.

Comment: Keep a reference (make it a ivar) of the tap gesture.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? how?

Comment: Yes, Sorry I forgot to mark your answer as correct. I've done now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work 'cause you are removing a newly created gesture, not the gesture it already may have.
You must retrive the gestures array with `ValueLabel.gestureRecognizers` then remove each one with a for loop.